# How to Make Half Screen Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

ı want to make half ccreen Activity.(Not dialog / Popup).When I click the button, I want the activity as a half screen before the main activity closes.Dialogs and popups don't help me do what I want. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: For this kind of use case fragments are used. try using fragments on top of activity to achieve the same.

Comment: I want activity, not fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create An activity with transparent background and toolbar.

apply this style to your activity via manifest.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".TransparentActivity"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Define you activity XML with 50% background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context=".TransparentActivity">

       <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>  

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```